# Kotlin built-in regex: Escape all regex metacharacters in a string with backslash

Tags: regex, kotlin

As you probably all know, regular expressions have some metacharacters, such as `\`, `|`, `.`, `?`, `+`, `*`,….  If you want to search for a substring including one of these characters without actually using the regex behaviour, you can escape it with a backslash.

So if you want to search for `"Is it true?"` in a string you would use the pattern
`"Is it true\?"`.

I am using Kotlin and its built-in regular expressions. Is there a way in Kotlin (a function or something) to get a string from another string in which all of the special characters in the input string are escaped?

So if the input to such a function were `"This is good."` the output would be `"This is good\."`, and for `"? a [+"` it would be `"\? a \[\+"`.  → every regex special character in the output is escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Are you looking for https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/escape.html?

Comment: Frame challenge: if you want to search for a literal string, why are you using a regex? There are simpler (and more efficient) [ways](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/index-of.html) [to](/questions/51238456/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-kotlin) search for a literal string.

Comment: @gidds Good to raise alternatives, but in general, there is a use case for regex-escaping, as the literal string may well be part of a bigger regex.

Comment: Yes Regex.escape (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/escape.html) is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I was trying escapeReplacement but that didn't work.  Glad I found your comment...